# ImportError: cannot import name 'SnliReader' from 'allennlp.data.dataset_readers'

Tags: importerror, allennlp

I am beginner in understanding Allennlp framework.
I tried the code given in medium post https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/fine-tuning-bert-with-allennlp-7459119b736c.

But, got an ImportError: cannot import name 'SnliReader' from 'allennlp.data.dataset_readers'

Does any one know why this error is showing?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like that blog post is based on an older version of allennlp. For version 2.x, the `SnliReader` can be found in the allennlp-models package; specifically at `allennlp_models.pair_classification.dataset_readers.snli`.